# iPhone won't boot after installing IOS9

Tags: macos, iphone, startup

I downloaded IOS9 with the phone and went through the the location service and other yes/no screens. 
I got to the screen that said lets get started and after that I just got the Apple logo and a progress bar, then the main screen for half a second then the progress bar again.
I did a hard reset and now it is stuck on the logo/progress bar screen. Well that's not quite true; if you wait for several minutes the progress bar disappears and then comes back. It always only gets to one third by the way.
I tried connecting to iTunes to download the build again but it tells me I have to respond on my iPhone. Which I can't because it's locked up.
Does anyone have any ideas please? I'm getting a bit desperate.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that, after a frustrating hour, I went out and bought some beer and milk. When I came back, the phone seemed to work, though occasionally I still get the logo/status bar screen.
Maybe now I can re-download the software with iTunes, perhaps it was corrupted before. Anyway, it seems that the solution is to go out and buy refreshments :-) or, al least, leave it alone for an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

READ FIRST: Before you attempt the following instructions, know that if things go south, you may lose your data, so I hope that you have a recent backup to restore to, just in case.

1. Plug your iPhone into iTunes.
2. Hold the power button and home button together, as if you were doing a force restart, but keep holding them together, even after you see an Apple logo. Wait until you see a "Connect To iTunes" screen.
3. Select "Update" from the window that will appear.